# How does `:` in `on:click` work, in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, dom-events, svelte

I am experimenting with Svelte and following the official tutorial. At https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-assignments, I am instructed to use this line of code:

```js
<button on:click={handleClick}>
```

What is the purpose of the colon? Why isn't it simply `<button onclick=...`?

I found the [Svelte API documentation on element directives](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_element_event), which provides usage examples within Svelte, but I still don't understand how this is valid JS syntax, or how it is transformed to such. I don't understand how the colon *works* (as separate from understanding its *usage*).

I can understand that this was a way to implement a single directive for all DOM event attributes, but its actual functioning is not that transparent to me.

Comment: Vue uses `@click`, Angular uses `(click)` etc.  As mentioned below it's not valid, it's run through some compilation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Others have explained the point about it being compiled into JavaScript, so I'll address this part:

> Why isn't it simply `<button onclick=...`?

The `onclick` attribute is an existing HTML attribute (that you shouldn't use). The semantics are very different — the string value is evaluated as JavaScript when the click happens. It's a bad practice because any functions you call must live in the *global* scope.

`on:click` is a Sveltism that links the button's click event to a *locally* defined function. The `:` is a generic piece of syntax that says 'this is a *directive* rather than an *attribute*' — where 'directive' can mean an event handler (`on:...`), a binding (`bind:...`), a transition (`in:...`/`out:...`/`transition:...`) and so on.

Comment: pardon me if this is a stupid question, svelte is a compiler right? so does that mean it reads this file with the on:click and generates some JS code from it which is what the browsers eventually run? how does it generate platform specific JS code?

Comment: Visit the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl), click 'JS Output'. All will be revealed

Answer (score 6):

The first thing to understand is that the code in Svelte components is actually not the resulting JavaScript that is sent to the browser, so about:

> I still don't understand how this is valid JS syntax

It is not. It is "compiled" into valid JavaScript by SvelteJS's compiler.

I have not roamed through the source code, but I presume the colon in this case, is used to denote the event handler binding directive (`on`) from the event itself (`click`).

---

For an actual demonstration of the compilation: you can visit the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.14.1) and select the "Js output" tab to see the compiled JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

The svelte `<button on:click ...  />` becomes after the compilation step a normal event listener for the event "click" on that button. 
getEventListeners(elem) will reveal that. Thats why multiple handlers are possible,
for example `<button on:click on:doWhatever...`>
So, equivalent to add elem.addEventListener() in plain js.

Answer (score 1):

As of Svelte 5 the prop will be called `onclick`:

https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/docs/event-handlers